# What is the boolean data type in C++

Tags: c++, types, boolean

I'm doing some exercise where I need to use a boolean. However when I try to create one as `Boolean` the compiler does not accept it. What is the name of the boolean type in C++?

Comment: 1) C# is not C++. 2) How come you don't have a way to backup? Aren't you using version control? 3) You should learn *some* C++ (or whatever language) before writing it. I think this is too basic a question. I recommend grabbing a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Do you have [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: You totally just destroyed his question (in a good way).

Comment: @BoltClock: what do you mean? Did I misunderstood something? Was the question about something else?

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: Well, it started off as a convoluted life story + rant. My comment was just a joke.

Answer (score 1):

The boolean datatype in C++ is `bool` as in:

```
bool myBool = true;
```